# Как вызвать функцию из родительского файла, в дочернем файле

Tags: python

возможно ли вызвать ИЗ дочернего файла, функцию, которая находится В родительском файле?

**parent.py:**

```
import testfile

def test1():
    print('test1')
    testfile.test2()

def test3():
    print('test3')

test()
```

**testfile.py**

```
def test2():
    print('test2')
    test3() #эта функция находится в parent.py
```

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да, верно. Жаль, что я не смог найти это раньше.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете передать вашу родительскую функцию в аргумент во время запуска функции дочернего файла

**parent.py**

```
import testfile

def test1():
    print('test1')
    testfile.test2(test3)

def test3():
    print('test3')

test1()
```

**testfile.py**

```
def test2(func):
    print('test2')
    func()
```

**RESULT**

> test1 test2 test3

Comment: Ух ты! Хорошая идея, большое спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста), рад что идея понравилась поскольку я только недавно вышел из уровня Junior в Middle на python)